# mkstemp opening too many files

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess.run` in a loop (more than 10 000 times) to call some java command.
Like this:

```
 import subprocess
 import tempfile

 for i in range(10000):
     ret = subprocess.run(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
     (_, name) = tempfile.mkstemp()
     with open(name, 'w+') as fp:
         fp.write(ret.stdout.decode())
```

However, after some time, I got the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 5, in <module>
    ret = subprocess.run(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1454, in _execute_child
    errpipe_read, errpipe_write = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Am I missing something to close some file descriptor?
Thanks

Comment: use with on `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`, instead of creating it, them opening another instance into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mkstemp` returns an **already open** file descriptor `fd` followed by the filename.  You are ignoring the file descriptor (your choice of the name `_` suggests you have explicitly chosen to ignore it) and as a result you are neglecting to close it. Instead, you open the file a second time using the filename, creating a file object that contains a *second* file descriptor for the same file.  Regardless of whether you close that second one, the first one remains open.

Here's a fix to the `mkstemp` approach:

```
 temporaryFiles = []
 for i in range(1000):
     ...
     fd, name = tempfile.mkstemp()
     os.write(fd, ... )
     os.close(fd)
     temporaryFiles.append(name)  # remember the filename for future processing/deletion
```

Building on Wyrmwood's suggestion in the comments, an even better approach would be:

```
 temporaryFiles = []
 for i in range(1000):
     ...
     with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
         # tmp is a context manager that will automatically close the file when you exit this clause
         tmp.file.write( ... )
         temporaryFiles.append(tmp.name)  # remember the filename for future processing/deletion
```

Note that both `mkstemp` and the `NamedTemporaryFile` constructor have arguments that allow you to be more specific about the file's location (`dir`) and naming (`prefix`, `suffix`). If you want to keep the files, you should specify `dir` so that you keep them out of the default temporary directory, since the default location may get cleaned up by the OS.

Comment: You could add how to use the `with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:` to ensure open/close

Comment: @Wyrmwood   From `tempfile.mkstemp.__doc__`:  "Caller is responsible for deleting the file when done with it." vs `tempfile.TemporaryFile.__doc__`:   "The file has no name, and will cease to exist when it is closed."   From the question it looks like OP doesn't want the files to be quite *that* temporary

Comment: Thanks for the already opened. Indeed, it's used a bit as a logging stuff, but I will try to deal with it. Thanks.

Comment: @bloubib  You might want to investigate the `logging` module

Comment: The fix is then to replace _ with fd and adding os.close(fd).

Comment: @jez - If he wants to keep the files, tempfile is probably the wrong library :-) Even though calling mkstemp directly means you are responsible for cleanup, it is in the POSIX /tmp folder on a linux distro, and since *POSIX suggests this is flushed as boot* it's not a great place for files you want keep. Probably OK though with what you suggested, if he does not intend to keep them after program execution.